# Visual Studio code how to sync code from zip download with code on server

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitlab

I am using visual studio code 1.22.
Since last time I used

```
git clone http://linkofmycode_on_gitlab
```

to clone code back to my local machine it tooks so long. So I decided to download zip file directly and open and edit on it.
Now I want to submit my new editing code to that develop branch and pull if there is any update but I dont know how to do.
Normally if I use git clone from the start then I can do

```
git remote add origin http://link...
```

but now it shows "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should initialize your repository. Try this command **git init**, then add origin like you always do.